# From a group that is 60% female, 8 are chosen. Probability that 2 will be female?

Tags: probability

Please show me how to calculate this one. A group is 60 percent female. Out of a random sample of 8, what is the probability that 2 will be female

Answer (score 1):

The probability that ***exactly*** two will be female:

$$P(\text{female})\times P(\text{female}) \times \Big(P(\text{not female})\Big)^6$$$$\dfrac{6}{10}\times \dfrac{6}{10}\times \left(\dfrac{4}{10}\right)^6$$

To calculate the probability that ***at least*** two are female, calculate the probability of (no female or exactly one female) is chosen, and subtract this probability from $1$ to find the probability of two or more females selected.

Comment: Is it also possible to use the binomial formula to calculate the probability?